# Can TensorFlow take external Python functions when training a NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train an autoencoder but having already known the decoder (which is a `python` function). My idea is to train the encoder and feed the latent space to an already known decoder, which is a function in `python` I already have. So, I am wondering if there is a way to train the encoder by adding the decoder function, but without losing parallelization over GPU. The part of code related to one training iteration would be like this:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    latent_space = encoder(x_batch, training=True) # NN model
    output = decoder(latent_space) # Python function
    loss_value = loss(y_batch, output)
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, encoder.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

where `encoder` is a neural network and `decoder` is the aforementioned `python` function. How can I include this function and have GPU parallelization? Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TensorFlow can take external Python functions.

What you are looking for is the `tf.py_function()`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function

Please note that if you want to use external Python code this is the only solution, to wrap into the `tf.py_function()`.

Comment: You can also use eager mode